# Orbeon Form - Is there anyway to disallow download attachment by default?

Tags: orbeon

I found a useful document about it: https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/attachment

Therefore I did a similar approach, I added this line in properties-local.xml:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxg.xforms.xbl.fr.attachment.allow-download" value="false"/>
```

but it doesn't work. When I created Form Builder and added attachment, the setting still marked allow download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you just have a typo. Try the following (with the property name starting with `oxf` instead of `org`). I've tried this locally and it is working for me.

```xml
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.xforms.xbl.fr.attachment.allow-download"
    value="false"/>
```

Comment: thanks @avernet, I tried again and it works. However when I create Form Builder and add Attachment control, in control setting window I still see it enable 'Allow download' eventhough in Form Runner it is disabled. Any idea about this? I think it should uncheck in control setting window.

Comment: @songokuuu I agree that this is confusing; Form Builder should most likely show 3 options (Use default, Yes, No), as done in other places. Let us give some thoughts to this one, and I'll then follow-up here. -Alex

Comment: @songokuuu For a reference, the change discussed in the last two messages is tracked as [#5050](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/5050). -Alex

Comment: that's great! Many thanks